# Hibernate 4 remove entity with oneToMany collection

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm trying to delete User entity from DB

```
//whatever
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user", orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Filter> filters = new HashSet<Filter>();
//whatever

//whatever
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.DETACH})
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
private User user;
//whatever
```

but getting:
ERROR SqlExceptionHelper:146 - Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`web_app_db`.`filters`, CONSTRAINT `FK_8oeay5yddrcgd4i71m1yda1hb` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`user_id`))

orphanRemoval = true not working, what should I do?

Comment: Is both is the user and the filters in the same entity? THe private Set<Filter> filters = new HashSet, seems wrong. Maybe you can get rid of the = new HashSet<Filter>(); Can you show how you generating the Ids, but it is probably best to the whole entity at least with private variables. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
private User user;
```

Comment: @JohnJohnson May you show me the whole entity of the Filter and the User entity.